# How do I copy an SSH key from a Mac to a Windows machine?

Tags: windows, macos, git, ssh-keys

I have a public SSH key on my MacBook, but am trying to access a host that requires it on my desktop.

How do I do that, and where do I put it on my Windows machine?

I am using gitGui on Windows and terminal `git` on OS X.

Comment: Why don't you just generate another key for your desktop?

Comment: This seems more a question for [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 4):

Copy the files from `/Users/< username >/.ssh/` to `C:\Users\< username >\.ssh`

Replace "Users" with "Documents and Settings" if you are on Windows XP or later.
You can just copy the files with a flash drive.

Comment: The path, in Mavericks at least, is now `/Users/< username >/.ssh/`. Note the plurality of `Users`. Thanks for this!

Comment: You probably wanted to mention `Windows XP or older`?